# Blur Tween in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, blur, tween

I wish for a movie clip to slowly blur over a couple of seconds. Is there some way to do this without using Tweener or some other external class? I only wish to use the tween class.

The code I use at the moment is below, but this doesn't do it gradually, just turns the blur on like a switch:

```
var blur : BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();
blur.blurX = 4;
blur.blurY = 4;
blur.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
chrNicky.filters = [blur];
```

I need the blur to happen over the course of two seconds.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the following article I wrote few years ago:

[Adding Directional Motion Blur to APE (AS Physics Engine)](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2008/11/23/adding-directional-motion-blur-to-ape/)

My article also includes an isolated Flex-sample which demonstrates how to add directional motion blur to a tween. Also it explains the how the implementation works in principle.

[Download Directional Motion Blur Sample](http://npacemo.com/sample-applications/DirectionalMotionBlur.zip)